# Why cancel button is missing from text composing while sharing content through message?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented share button in Swift using following code:

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let textToShare = [ "Text to share" ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Everything seems working but when I share content through message then the cancel button is missing from text composing to return back if I change my mind sharing it.
[image]

Comment: did you check cancel button clickable below battery icon ?

Comment: @ivarun It is clickable. It is the color problem then. How to fix that?

Comment: Cancel button is visible but color is white so it matches with background color.

Comment: @technerd yes that's the problem. Just realized. But how to change the color back when the cancel button is pressed?

Comment: @MaihanNijat check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change navigation bar tint color in your app using below code:

in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

replace red with color that you want to set in button.

Comment: Thanks. When I press cancel the current NavigationController color remains red.

Comment: The cancel button is red now but when I press cancel then the main ViewController Navigation bar color remains red which is white initially.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS 11, This solution was good for me although not excellent.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]
    }];
}

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
        //set your app color
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor APPCOLOR]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor APPCOLOR]
        }];
    }
```

PS: I try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228461/mfmessagecomposer-cancel-button-not-visible-in-ios-11) solution also but does not work for me.